# #Python iterate over an array with empty (nan) values

Tags: python, arrays, loops, nan

In advance, thank you for the time.

The problem is as follows, I have a matrix where both "0" and "empty fields" are necessary in the further calculation:

as data is converted into a numpy array, it automatically replaces the empty fields with "nan" ... how can I loop over each row of an array while ignoring the "nan" values for further calculation .

```
>>>data

    [[ 2.  4.  7.]
     [ 7.  0. nan]
     [-3.  7. 0.]
     [nan nan  6.]]
```

The idea was to run a set of conditions while iterating over the rows and possibly append to a new numpy array but for simplicity let's say I just want to get a new array without the "nan" so the final result would look something like >

```
>>>final_data

     [[2,4,7], [7,0], [-3,7,0], [6]]
```

Comment: Could you please also add your input data?

Comment: You might want to check the [numpy.isnan](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) function

Comment: its a csv file ... which is loaded into a panda dataframe and converted  by the data.values

Comment: @gvladja, if you want to apply a function to your Pandas Dataframe, just use the [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) function, the nan values will be automatically ignored

Comment: I'm fairly new to this so I apologise in advance...
the reason I have converted it into a matrix is that way it ignores all the string data. If I apply the .applymap() method then I run into a problem of pandas keeping the column names and thus unable to iterate over the dataframe ( and I cant seem to find how to ignore the colum names (remove lables?) )
As the output should eventually be an array, it felt like converting it into a numpy array was a good way to proceed.